# ADB push -p Bad file descriptor

Tags: android, adb, push

ADB command:

```
adb pull -p /data/local/tmp/myFile.txt c:\myFile.txt
```

return text "**Transferring: 11468800/38632644 (29%)**"

But if I use command:

```
adb push -p c:\myFile.txt /data/local/tmp/myFile.txt
```

I can see error: "**cannot stat 'c:\myFile.txt': Bad file descriptor**".

**adb help** contains text

```
adb push [-p] <local> <remote>
    - copy file/dir to device
    ('-p' to display the transfer progress)
```

What is wrong?

- Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
- OS: Win8.1
- FileSystem: NTFS

Comment: It could be a permissions problem. Have you tried pulling to a location you might be more likely to be able to write to? Like C:\Users\<username>\

Comment: No. Cmd have Admin permissions. Files like C:\Users\<username>\* have this problem.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem. I removed the "-p", removed the "_" from my file name, and moved it to a different location and it worked.

Comment: Actually, removing `-p` helped :)

Comment: The -p argument is mainly used to determe "WHAT ON THE EARTH,THIS PROGRAM IS DOING WHILE PUSHING A BIG FILE TO THE DEVICE" :).

Comment: @ShihabSoft Of course. But that doesn't help if it breaks the wohle process instead.

Answer (score 5):

Seems the argument handling of `adb push` is broken somehow. When using **-p** it seems to think that it is an argument (local file/dirname) and will treat the actual filename as remote file/dirname which will obviously not work as it's missing the preceding remote path. When using **-p** at the end copying does not seem to start at all.